# How can I convert a "Month Year" string to a date object in R?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to combine full month name and year data to get Year-Month data, but I'm having some trouble getting R to read the Month as a date object. The example below returns all NAs in the 'Date' column after passing it through `as.Date()`. Is there a better way to go about this? Thanks!

```
Month <- c('January','July','January')
Year <- c('2020','2020','2021')
df <- data.frame(Month, Year)
df$Date <- paste(df$Month, df$Year)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Year, format = "%B %Y")

df$Date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a day as well to create the `Date`

```
df$Date <- as.Date(paste(df$Date, 1), format = "%B %Y %d")
```